# urllib.openurl treating http links as local file addresses

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib

Trying to write a really basic scraper for youtube video titles, using a csv of video links and beautiful soup. The script as it currently stands is:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import csv

with open('url-titles-list.csv', 'wb') as csv_out:
    fieldnames = ['url', 'title']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_out, fieldnames = fieldnames)
    with open('url-nohttps-list.csv', 'rb') as csv_in:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csv_in, fieldnames=['linkurls'])
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in reader:
            link = row['linkurls']
            with urllib.urlopen(link) as response:
                html = response.read()
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
                name = soup.title.string
                writer.writerow({'url': row['linkurls'], 'title': name})
```

This breaks at `urllib.urlopen(link)`, with the following traceback making it look like the url type is not getting recognised correctly, and it's trying to open links as local files?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/clarapouletty/Desktop/operation_find_yuzusho/fetcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    with urllib.urlopen(link) as response:
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 213, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 469, in open_file
    return self.open_local_file(url)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 483, in open_local_file
    raise IOError(e.errno, e.strerror, e.filename)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'linkurls'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any assistance much appreciated!

Comment: have you verified what `link` is immediately before callugin `urllib.urlopen`? Perhaps it's not what you think it is.

Comment: Thanks @BryanOakley, I thought the csv column needed to be named for this but apparently that was a mistake!